# How do I allow spaces in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm such an amateur at regex, how do I allow spaces(doesn't matter how many) in this regex?

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $str)) return FALSE;
```

Comment: That regular expression already allows spaces.

Comment: I think the question is confusing because of a double negative. Do you want your regex to allow spaces, or the overall condition to allow spaces?

Comment: :space: or \s for any whitespace, or :blank: for tab/space

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_ -]/', $str)) return FALSE;
```

Note that I put the space before the hyphen.  If the space were after the hyphen, I would be specifying a character range from underscore to space.  (Issue also evadable by putting a backslash before the hyphen to escape it.)

This is assuming that what you mean by "allow" is: this regex is being used to validate a character string, and if it *matches*, then the character string is *disallowed* (hence `return FALSE`).  So the characters in the negated character class (`[^...]`) are actually the *allowed* characters.  (This is causing some general confusion in this question.)

Answer (score 16):

the `\s` in the regular expretion like this `'/[^A-Za-z0-9_-\s]/'`
mean the space

Answer (score 2):

Not so much an answer to your question, but a site I find useful for [checking regex expressions](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It also explains what each part of the expression does / means as you hover over it in the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. The regular expression, as it stands, will succeed if `$str` has any character in it that is not `A-Za-z0-9_-`. Since a space is not one of these characters, the regular expression will match, and the whole statement returns `FALSE`.

If this isn't what you want, and you want your regular expression to match if `$str` has any character that is not in `A-Za-z0-9_-` or  a space, then you need to change it to `A-Za-z0-9_ -` (note the space between the underscore and the hyphen). Thus when your string has a character that is not `A-Za-z0-9_ -`, the regular expression will match, and your statement will return `FALSE`. If your string is made up entirely of `A-Za-z0-9_ -`, then the regular expression will fail to match, and your processing will continue to the next line.

**Edit:** Here's an example: If your string is `abc123def`, currently the regular expression will not match and you will not return `FALSE`. If your string is `abc123 def`, the regular expression will match and the statement will return `FALSE`. If you change the character class to `A-Za-z0-9_ -`, then the regular expression will fail to match for both `abc123def` and `abc123 def`, and you will not return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ALLOW only space you'll need '/ /'

If you need to ALLOW any whitespace char (space, tab, newline) - use '/\s/'

And if you need to add a space to your pattern (means to ignore space) - use /[^A-Za-z0-9_\ -]/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a literal blank space in your negated character class.

It would be more concise to use:

- the case-insensitive flag `i` and omit one of the letter ranges
- and write `[0-9]` as `\d`

like this:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9_ -]/i', $str)) return FALSE;
```

but even better would be to use `\w` which represents [A-Za-z0-9_] (which is most of your pattern) to write:

```
if (preg_match('/[^\w -]/', $str)) return FALSE;
```

This pattern states that if `$str` contains any character not in `[A-Za-z0-9_ -]` then `false` will be returned.